# Plot of continuous function cuts off

Tags: plotting, functions

Why the following plot cuts off at integer points ?

```
Plot[Cos[Pi IntegerPart[x]]
  Min[Abs[FractionalPart[x]], Abs[FractionalPart[x] - 1]], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

**Update**

It gets connected when you add `Exclusions -> None` as an option, but It is not clear why this function has exclusive points, since it is continuous. Also it gets connected if you increase the `PlotPoints` (thanks to the comments). Also why at `x=9` the cut is more severe than say at `x=1` or `x=2` ?

Can someone explain what is the issue here, and how these two options solve(or maybe hide) the issue ?

Comment: add the option `Exclusions -> None`?

Comment: The gaps don't occur with `"11.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 16, 2017)"`

Comment: add the option PlotPoints -> 500 helps

Comment: I think this is an interesting question. I think that the function is continuous, so why are points excluded?

Comment: The question is not "how can I make the plot continuous", but why the plot cuts off, and why at `x=9` it is more severe than say at `x=1` or `x=2`. As @mikado mentioned the function is continuous, then whats the issue ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This behavior has been evolving ever since *Mathematica* was created.
Something different happens in V11 than in V10. (I'm unable to go back further.)
I'll describe V10 first, since its behavior conforms to the OP.

***IN V10,*** the gaps are because the functions `FractionalPart` and `IntegerPart` are discontinuous, which makes the gaps symmetric.  In plotting, *Mathematica* does not check limits at their discontinuities to see if the expression being plotted happens to be continuous. Rather, it assumes the discontinuities in the component functions propagate to discontinuities in the plot and puts a little gap in the plot at each one.

I assume this choice (not to check limits) was made for the sake of speed. The discontinuities are identified by a time-constrained symbolic analysis of the function.

The size of the gap is determined by the sampling. With higher setting for `PlotPoints`, the smaller the gap.  The sampling can be observed using `Mesh -> All`.  The sampling is a result of an asymmetric recursive subdivision of "active" subintervals, which depends principally on the angles between successive line segments used to approximate the graph.  As a result, the gaps are not identical.

```
Plot[Cos[Pi IntegerPart[x]] Min[Abs[FractionalPart[x]], 
   Abs[FractionalPart[x] - 1]], {x, 0, 10}, Mesh -> All, 
 MeshStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The gaps are not visible at ordinary size with lots of plot points:

```
Plot[Cos[Pi IntegerPart[x]] Min[Abs[FractionalPart[x]], 
   Abs[FractionalPart[x] - 1]], {x, 0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 1000]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another approach, mentioned by @kglr in a comment, is to turn off the processing with `Exclusions -> None`.

```
Plot[Cos[Pi IntegerPart[x]] Min[Abs[FractionalPart[x]], 
   Abs[FractionalPart[x] - 1]], {x, 0, 10}, Exclusions -> None]
```

***IN V11,*** `Plot` adds sampling points close to the discontinuity.  It still does not connect the lines, but if the function is continuous, the gap should be imperceptible.

```
plot = Plot[
  Cos[Pi IntegerPart[x]] Min[Abs[FractionalPart[x]], Abs[FractionalPart[x] - 1]],
  {x, 0, 10}, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red]
Count[plot, _Line, Infinity]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(*  20  <-- number of continuous lines *)
```

One continuous line is created with `Exclusions -> None`:

```
Count[
 Plot[Cos[Pi IntegerPart[x]] Min[Abs[FractionalPart[x]], 
    Abs[FractionalPart[x] - 1]], {x, 0, 10}, Exclusions -> None],
 _Line, Infinity]
(*  1  <-- number of continuous lines *)
```

Comment: I believe this happens exactly in v11.0. `Exclusions` is updated at that time. Legacy document: https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v11/ref/Exclusions.html

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is to define a numeric function, effectively hiding the (potential) discontinuities from `Plot`:

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := Cos[Pi IntegerPart[x]] Min[Abs[FractionalPart[x]],
   Abs[FractionalPart[x] - 1]]
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

```
Count[%, _Line, Infinity]
```

> 1

Comment: According to the OP: "[The question is not "how can I make the plot continuous", but why the plot cuts off, and why at x=9 it is more severe than say at x=1 or x=2.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143692/plot-of-continuous-function-cuts-off#comment386571_143692)"

Comment: @Rahul. The "why" is because `Plot` "sees" the embedded discontinuous functions, as illustrated by hiding them and making the problem go away. Whats your point?

Comment: My point is only that your answer does not directly address the OP's question, except implicitly.

Comment: +1 this is interesting confirmation of the explanation given by @MichaelE2