# A Trial Boundary Element Approach to Solving Integral Equation

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, numerics, solidmechanics

I am trying to numerically solve an integral equation in Starfield and Crouch textbook (Boundary Element Methods in Solid Mechanics: With Applications in Rock Mechanics and Geological Engineering), equation 3.2.5 (see code). After computing the density `py` I attempted to plot `uy` vs `x`. I observed some numerical instabilities in the region `0<=x<=1`. I Increased my number of integration points,`np` and also reduced my boundary element size,`xe`, I still observe the same irregularity.I'm not sure why this is happening. Is there something I'm not doing right? I would appreciate any guidance. Here is my code:
(I have added the corresponding analytic solution plot)

```
(*Boundary elements set up and material properties*)
nb = nm = 20; nd=ne=nb+1; G = 1; v = 0.1; L = 1.25;a = 0.1; 
(*Input the coordinates of the of ends of boundary elements (xe,ye)*)
xe = Table[i, {i, -1, 1, 2/nb}]; 
ye = Table[0, {i, 1, ne}]; 
(*Input the coordinates of the midpoints of boundary elements (xm,ym)*)

xm = ym = Table[0, {i, 1, nm}]; 
jb = If[j < ne, j + 1]; 
Do[xm[[j]] = (xe[[j]] + xe[[jb]])/2; 
  ym[[j]] = (ye[[j]] + ye[[jb]])/2, {j, 1, nm}];
bv = Table[-1, {i, 1, nm}]; 

(*Compute elements of Influence coefficients Bij and Sij*)

Sij = Bij = Table[0, {i, 1, nb}, {j, 1, nb}]; 
uy = (1/(2 G Pi)) (-2 (1 - v) (Log[Sqrt[(x - xi)^2 + y^2]] - 
    Log[L - xi]) + y^2/((x - xi)^2 + y^2))(*Equation 3.2.5*); 
Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"]; 
np = 6; points = weights = Table[Null, {np}]; 
Do[points[[i]] = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, -1, 1][[i, 1]], {i, 1, np}]
Do[weights[[i]] = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, -1, 1][[i, 2]], {i, 1, np}]
GuassInt[f_, z_] := Sum[(f /. z -> points[[i]])*weights[[i]], {i, 1, np}]
Do[xb = (1/2)*(xe[[jb]]*(1 - z) + xe[[j]]*(1 + z)); yb = (1/2)*(ye[[jb]]*(1 -z) + ye[[j]]*(1 + z)); 
Do[Bij[[i, j]] = GuassInt[uy /. {x -> xm[[i]], xi -> xb, y -> yb}, z]; Sij[[i, j]] = GuassInt[uy /. {x -> x, y -> yb, xi -> xb}, z], {i, 1, nb}], {j, 1, nb}]
py = LinearSolve[Bij, bv];
plot1 = Plot[Sij . py, {x, 0, 3},PlotStyle -> Blue]
AnalyticUy[h_] := -(1 - ((Log[h + Sqrt[(h^2) - 1]])/Log[2]))
plot2 = Plot[AnalyticUy[h], {h, 1, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black}]
plot3 = Plot[-1, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black}]
Show[plot1, plot2, plot3]
```

Here is my plot (see the red ellipse region).
[image: Plot of displacement uy vs x]

Comment: When I increase `np` to `20`, I find the irregularity has reduced significantly.

Comment: It would be far easier to tell is you would explain what you are doing there...

Comment: Anyways, 10-point Gauss quadrature is quite high. Are you sure you want to do that? Maybe increasing the number of elements is a better option...

Comment: @xzczd, yes it does reduce with increased `np`, the but instability is still there. That segment of the plot should be a straight line, (i.e,` uy(x,y=0) = - 1`, as per the Boundary condition for `0<=x<=1` at least up to the edge `x= 1`, where some jumps may be expected.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, I am trying to solve a lubricated rigid die problem in an elastic half-space,y<=0. `uy` represents the displacement of the surface as a result of the rigid die indentation. For the surface directly under the die, the displacement, `uy=-1`. The displacement of any other points in the `y<=0` region can then be computed once we determine the stress density, `py(xi)`

Comment: I appreciate that you have edited your code. However, it throws errors because `xe` has the wrong number of elements. Probably you would like to have `xe = Table[i, {i, -1, 1, 2/nb}];` in your code. Moreover, I would advise you to compute `nd`, `ne` and `nm` from `nb` if possible; this way you have fewer place to change whenever you change parameters.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher. Yeah thanks for the catch. `xe` should be as you defined it. That was a typo in my edits. I have now edited it. I'm still not sure why I am having the numerical instability though.

Comment: Er… the lubricated rigid die problem is described by a PDE with some b.c.s, right? Then I really suggest you to add them to your question, that'll make your question more attractive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's basically nothing wrong with your code. (Though it can be conciser. ) It's the improper parameters that make trouble. As mentioned by [Henrik Schumacher](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38178/henrik-schumacher) in the comment above, increasing the number of elements improves the solution. Also, it turns out that the node number for the calculation of `Sij` plays an important role here. Using `4 np` nodes for the calculation of `Sij` and increasing `nb` to `100`, I got the following result:

```
(*Boundary elements set up and material properties*)
nb = nm = 100; nd = ne = nb + 1; G = 1; v = 0.1; L = 1.25; a = 0.1;
(*Input the coordinates of the of ends of boundary elements (xe,ye)*)
xe = Table[i, {i, -1, 1, 2/nb}];
ye = Table[0, {i, 1, ne}];
(*Input the coordinates of the midpoints of boundary elements (xm,ym)*)
{xm, ym} = MovingAverage[#, 2] & /@ {xe, ye};
bv = Table[-1, {i, 1, nm}];
(*Compute elements of Influence coefficients Bij and Sij*)
uy = {x, xi, y} \[Function] (-2 (1 - v) (Log[Sqrt[(x - xi)^2 + y^2]] - Log[L - xi]) + 
   y^2/((x - xi)^2 + y^2))/(2 G π)(*Equation 3.2.5*);
(*Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"];
*)
np = 4;
(*GuassInt[f_,z_,pts_]:=Module[{points,weights},{points,weights}=Transpose@\
GaussianQuadratureWeights[pts,-1,1];(f/.z\[Rule]points).weights];*)
gaussInt[f_, z_, domain_, points_: np] := 
  Module[{nodes, weights}, {nodes, weights} = 
    Most[NIntegrate`GaussRuleData[points, MachinePrecision]];
   -Subtract @@ domain weights.(Function @@ {z, f})@Rescale[nodes, {0, 1}, domain]];

{xb, yb} = MovingAverage[#, {1 + z, 1 - z}] & /@ {xe, ye};
Bij = Table[gaussInt[uy[xm[[i]], xb[[j]], yb[[j]]], z, {-1, 1}, np], {i, nb}, {j, nb}];
Sij = Table[gaussInt[uy[x, xb[[j]], yb[[j]]], z, {-1, 1}, 4 np], {j, nb}];
py = LinearSolve[Bij, bv];
plot1 = Plot[Sij.py, {x, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
AnalyticUy[h_] := -(1 - ((Log[h + Sqrt[(h^2) - 1]])/Log[2]))
plot2 = Plot[AnalyticUy[h], {h, 1, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black}];
plot3 = Plot[-1, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black}];
Show[plot1, plot2, plot3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I've simplified the code a bit. The introduction for `` NIntegrate`GaussRuleData `` can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6966/1871).

> **Remark**
>
> Because of the issue mentioned in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143692/1871), you need to add `Exclusions` option, or make the expression a black box, or simply turn to `ListLinePlot` to get the same result as above if you're in *v11.2*. (Not sure if *v10* is influenced. )
>
> ```
>  (* Workaround 1 *)
>  plot1 = 
>    Plot[Sij.py, {x, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Thin, Blue}, Exclusions -> None];
>  (* Workaround 2 *)
>  cf = Compile[x, #] &[Sij.py]; 
>  plot1 = Plot[cf@x, {x, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotTheme -> "Classic"];
>  (* Workaround 3 *)
>  plot1 = ListLinePlot[Table[Sij.py, {x, 0, 3, 0.01}], PlotStyle -> Blue, 
>                       DataRange -> {0, 3}];
> ```
>
> to get the same result as mine if you're in *v11.2*.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input in making the code work better. While the noise is significantly reduced, I still observe some instability when I ran your code on my Mathematica v.11. I will accept your improvement as an answer if no other shot is being thrown at the question. Meanwhile, the boundary condition for the die` (-1<=x<=1)` are: For displacement, `uy(x,0)= -1`. This is given by `bv=-1`in the code and for stress; `Sigma yy= py(x)`.

Comment: At xzczd,by the way, why do you use `4 np` in computing the `Sij`matrix? I actually re-tried the code with just np instead & the instability is gone, except near the edge of the rigid die. Also can you kindly give a brief explanation of this line in the code `gaussInt[f_, z_, domain_, points_: np] := 
  Module[{nodes, weights}, {nodes, weights} = `
    Most[NIntegrate`GaussRuleData[points, MachinePrecision]];`
   -Subtract @@ domain weights.(Function @@ {z, f})@
      Rescale[nodes, {0, 1}, domain]];` My Mathematica vocabulary has not yet developed to this point.Thanks

Comment: @D.Andrew Interesting, this is related to an issue of plot introduced in _v11_ (or _v10_?). To see what has happened, try e.g. `Plot[Sij[[90]], {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All]`. I've added a workaround to the answer, check my edit.  As to `gaussInt`, `GaussRuleData` has been explained in the post linked above. If you're having difficulty with `@` and `@@`, `f@x` is equivalent to `f[x]`, `@@` is short for `Apply` so `-Subtract @@ domain` is amount to `domain[[2]] - domain[[1]]`. You may check this post: mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/1871

Comment: @ xzczd, thanks for the explanation and more clarification. My version is v11.1.1.0.